# imagecopyresampled resizes in chrome crops in ie/ff

Tags: php, image, gd, image-resizing

i have come across the following problem. i have made an thumbnailer with gd and when i run it in chrome this is what it does:

this is exactly what i expected it to do(resize it)

[screenshot taken in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9dFd.png)

sadly this is what firefox and ie do:(crop it)

[image taken in ff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEd1L.png)

i have the following code taking care of my resize:

```
// this image is created by another php file when text is filled in
$file = "hidden.png";
$size = GetImageSize($file);
if($size !== false){
$w = $size[0];
$h = $size[1];
//set new size
$nw = $_GET['width'];
$nh = ($nw*$h)/$w;
}
else{
//set new size
$nw = 400;
$nh = 200;
} 
//draw the image
$src_img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw,$nh);
imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
//resizing the    image
imagepng($dst_img);
imagedestroy($src_img);
imagedestroy($dst_img);
```

i have searched abit on stack and on google and the only thing i can find are solutions that are using css which i dont need since my image isnt constructed that way.

what do i need to do code-wise(not css related) to get it working correctly in all browsers?

if needed i can post more code

Comment: This is unlikely to be caused by the browser, as the resizing runs on server side. Have you done some debugging, what values are passed to the script? ("width" etc.)

Comment: +1 for a well-documented and nicely-written question. Bravo!

Comment: @Pekka웃 the value of width that is passed to the script show here is 300

Comment: @Robin are you 1000% sure that's what gets actually passed to the script? Have you done a `print_r($nw); print_r($nh);` in the script to confirm?

Comment: float(300) is normally a int
float(149.80132450331) is what var_dump gives me

Comment: @Pekka웃 when i call the page of the resize directly it show up correctly the resized image it crops when i call it in another page. and see above results are when i debug them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the question by merging the above script with my allready existing script to generate the image.

```
/* Get image info */
if(!isset($_POST['width']) && !isset($_POST['height']))
{
$width = '200';
$height = '100';
}
else
{
$width  = $_POST['width'] ;
$height = $_POST['height'];  
}
$Image = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height) ;
$sx = imagesx($Image) ;
$sy = imagesy($Image) ;
/*Check if RGB values have been set*/
if(!isset($_POST['r'])) {     $R = 255; } else {     $R = $_POST['r']; } 
if(!isset($_POST['g'])) {     $G = 255; } else {     $G = $_POST['g']; } 
if(!isset($_POST['b'])) {     $B = 255; } else {     $B = str_replace(")" , "" ,  $_POST['b']); }

/*Check if the text value is set   */
if(!isset($_POST['text'])) {$Text = "Uw tekst hier";}
else if($_POST['text'] == '') {$Text = "Uw tekst hier";}
else {$Text = $_POST['text'];}

/*Check if the font is set */
if(!isset($_POST['font'])) {$Font="./Fonts/arial.ttf" ;}
else{$Font= "./fonts/".$_POST['font'].".ttf";}

$FontColor = ImageColorAllocate ($Image,$R,$G,$B) ;    //TextColor
$FontShadow = ImageColorAllocate ($Image,0,0,0) ;   //BackGroundColor
$Rotation = 0 ;
/* Iterate to get the size up */
$FontSize=1 ;
do
    {
    $FontSize *= 1.1 ;
    $Box = @ImageTTFBBox($FontSize,0,$Font,$Text);
    $TextWidth = abs($Box[2] - $Box[6]) ;
    $TextHeight = abs($Box[3] - $Box[7]) ;
    }
while ($TextWidth < $sx*0.94) ;
/*  Awkward maths to get the origin of the text in the right place */ 
$x = $sx/2  - cos(deg2rad($Rotation))*$TextWidth/2;
$y = $sy/2  + sin(deg2rad($Rotation))*$TextWidth/2 + cos(deg2rad($Rotation))*$TextHeight/2 ;


imagefilledrectangle($Image, 0, 0, $sx , $sy , $FontShadow);
ImageTTFText ($Image,$FontSize,$Rotation,-$Box[6] ,-$Box[7],$FontColor,$Font,$Text);

if(isset($_POST['resize']) && $_POST['resize'] == 1)
{
    $nw = 400;
    $nh = 200;        

    $src_img = $Image;
    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw,$nh);
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $sx, $sy);//resizing    the image
    imagepng($dst_img, "hidden.png");
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    imagedestroy($dst_img); 
}
else
{
  //header('Content-type: image/png');
  Imagepng($Image, "hidden.png") ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has definitely nothing to do with the Browser, because that is not the way php works.
First of all the php-code gets interpreted on the server and then the result is past to the Client(Browser).

So in my opinion you should first check if the image generation is working correctly. Means that it produce every time the same Image. Then you should check this part:

```
if($size !== false){
   $w = $size[0];
   $h = $size[1];
   $nw = $_GET['width']; // <---- For Debugging set here a static number
   $nh = ($nw*$h)/$w;
}
```

Try to set for the debugging part, every variable which could change on each request to a fix value.

I hope i could help you

Comment: i have set all the local variables who could be changed with the program to fixed settings but it didnt fix anything sadly